# Can't get user while testing auth in laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, automated-tests, phpunit

I'm writing automated tests for a legacy laravel project, 5.8.38.
I have this test method.

```
public function testUserReceivesAnEmailWithAPasswordResetLink()
{
    Notification::fake();

    $user = factory(User::class)->create([
        'email' => 'john@example.com',
    ]);

    $this->post($this->passwordEmailPostRoute(), [
        'email' => 'john@example.com',
    ]);

    $this->assertNull($token = DB::table('password_resets')->first());
    Notification::assertSentTo($user, ResetPassword::class, function ($notification, $channels) use ($token) {
        return Hash::check($notification->token, $token->token) === true;
    });
}
```

This always fails because the user cannot be retrieved. The `passwordEmailPostRoute()` method goes to the `src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php sendResetLink()` method, eventually ending up in `src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php` at `retrieveByCredentials()` method.
This always returns null.

I tried dumping data and queries, but everything failed. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: try use : $this->actingAs($user,'api'); before $this->post

Comment: @OMR this hasn't solved my problem but seems to be a really helpful addition, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a very specific issue which I caused for myself.
My user factory generated wrong values for a morph connection field which prevented the return of a valid User object. I had to change the factory and the issue is now resolved.